# Javascript regex replace string on string

Tags: javascript, regex

This regex removes all after match the pattern and i need to remove only the match pattern and the value.

```
pattern = /(?<=ANO=).*/

 obj.where_str = " AND EMPRESA='CMIP' AND ANO='2019' AND MES='1' AND RHID='4207' AND TO_CHAR(DT_ADMISSAO,'YYYY-MM-DD')='2001-08-01' AND ESTADO='A'"

 obj.where_str = obj.where_str.replace(pattern, "'" + fieldValue + "'");
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is changing `.*` to `\S+` what you're looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Method 1

My guess is that maybe you're trying to write an expression similar to:

```
\bANO='([^']*)'
```

The desired value to replace is in the capturing group:

```
([^']*)
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/90Lg92/1/)

```js
const regex = /\bANO='([^']*)'/gm;
const str = ` AND EMPRESA='CMIP' AND ANO='2019' AND MES='1' AND RHID='4207' AND TO_CHAR(DT_ADMISSAO,'YYYY-MM-DD')='2001-08-01' AND ESTADO='A'`;
const subst = `ANO='Another_value_goes_here'`;

const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/8DNoPB/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/8DNoPB/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

And your code would probably look like:

```js
const regex = /\bANO='([^']*)'/g;
const str = ` AND EMPRESA='CMIP' AND ANO='2019' AND MES='1' AND RHID='4207' AND TO_CHAR(DT_ADMISSAO,'YYYY-MM-DD')='2001-08-01' AND ESTADO='A'`;
const fieldValue = 2020;
const subst = 'ANO=\''.concat(fieldValue, "'");
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

### Method 2

Another option would likely be:

```
(?<=\bANO=')\d{4}
```

which I guess/assume that there would no problem with a positive lookbehind.

#### [RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/OZEOfR/1/)

```js
const regex = /(?<=\bANO=')\d{4}/g;
const str = ` AND EMPRESA='CMIP' AND ANO='2019' AND MES='1' AND RHID='4207' AND TO_CHAR(DT_ADMISSAO,'YYYY-MM-DD')='2001-08-01' AND ESTADO='A'`;
const fieldValue = 2020;
const result = str.replace(regex, fieldValue);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: almost there ..i need to replace 2019 by another value

Comment: like obj.where_str = obj.where_str.replace(pattern, "'" + fieldValue + "'");

Comment: but ANO is a variable .... new RegExp(`/\b${variable}='([^']*)'/gm`)

Comment: why this dont work.... https://jsbin.com/guzocazapo/edit?html,js,console,output